# CORS and redirects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cors

I have a Rails application running on http://eu.app.foodev.com with [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) enable and the following configuration:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, 'Rack::Cors' do
  allow do
    origins /.*foodev\.com:\d*/
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options], expose: "Location"
  end
end
```

Here is the general idea of what I try to do:

1. Make a `GET` request on `/jobs/:id`
2. Server respond with a `303 See Other` with the `Location` header set to an other resource URL
3. Let user-agent follow the redirection to `GET` the other resource data by using the `Location` header.

Here are the request/response cycles. Beginning with the `OPTIONS` request:

```
OPTIONS http://foodev.com:3000/jobs/1
Accept:*/*
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, x-csrf-token
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Host:foodev.com:3000
Origin:http://eu.app.foodev.com:3000
```

And the response:

```
200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, x-csrf-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://eu.app.foodev.com:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Location
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain
```

Then finally the actual `GET http://foodev.com:3000/jobs/1` request:

```
GET http://foodev.com:3000/jobs/1
Accept:application/vnd.foo-v2+json
Host:foodev.com:3000
Origin:http://eu.app.foodev.com:3000
```

and the response:

```
303 See Other
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://eu.app.foodev.com:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Location
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Content-Length:185
Content-Type:application/json
Location:http://foodev.com:3000/skill_moderations/10
```

Since the response is a `303 See Other` (which is what I want) the user-agent (js) tries to follow the redirection, using the `Location` header but I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://foodev.com:3000/jobs/1. The request was redirected to 'http://foodev.com:3000/skill_moderations/10', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

[image]

The workflow here is good but I'm facing CORS issues I don't understand and don't known how to resolve. Any clues? Anyone faced this kind of flow before?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** It seems to be an issue with angular/restangular (which I'm using to make the requests). It actually works with the following jquery and $http commands:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://foodev.com:3000/jobs/1",
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
  },
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.foo-v2+json'
  },
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function (xhr, status) {
    console.log('error', status);
  }
});


$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$http.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/vnd.foo-v2+json';
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']
$http({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://foodev.com:3000/jobs/1",
  withCredentials: true,
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log(data);
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: why can't you just return the data from requested url? Worst case can do a cURL request to get it

Comment: because the `/jobs` endpoint may not have the data. It's absolutely not its responsibility to return "other resource" data.

Comment: then make request to endpoint whose responsibility it is to return the data ... might need multiple requests. Not likely to get around the CORS issue. Alternative is set up proxy on server that page resides on

Comment: thanks for the idea, i'll keep it in mind. However i'd like to see if someone has an idea to fix the issue mentioned here. Must be some misconfiguration or something.

Comment: no...preflight request (OPTIONS) needs to match or browsers will reject

Comment: it actually works with plain jquery ajax request using `crossDomain` option but not with my restangular agent. So it's a restangular/angular config issue, not a server side CORS config issue ;)

Comment: ok..my bad then and that is interesting. What difference do you see in headers?

Comment: it seems to be an issue with the `X-Requested-With` that is automatically added by jquery. I'm digging but here is a link https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1585

Comment: I've edited my question including the working ajax/$http request

Comment: yeah CORS spec says any extra headers will prompt a preflight but resolving that would only help for GET...will always preflight for post,put , delete etc

Comment: ok found my issue thanks to your last comment :) I had an extra header (CSRF token) which i actually don't need in this usecase (calling an API directly). Thanks man.